# Issue comparing two separate shapefiles

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, arcgis-10.4

I have two separate shapefiles (A&B) with road data that overlaps, but not in every place and they are very similar but do not line up perfectly. I want to compare them to each other, but they do not currently have a primary key, since they are from two different datasets.
[image]

First I tried Generating a Near table selecting only the closest B polygon to the A polygons, this worked however for some A polygons they had the same B Polygon so not all the B polygons were used.

What I need is a way so that every A polygon has a close B polygon that is only used for that one. Is there a way to do the near function so that each is only chosen once from shapefile B? It can be in python or I can pull them out and do it using SQL, I am currently using arc 10.4.

Answer (score 1):

From ArcMap Docs:

http://desktop.arcgis.com/es/desktop/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/near.htm

Maybe you are looking for spatial join:

http://desktop.arcgis.com/es/desktop/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/spatial-join.htm

Comment: No in my question i described that i used the near tool and that it does not produce the desired results. It will list the same object from shapefile B as being Near the shapefile A Object. I need to create a 1-1 comparison.

Comment: See my edited answer. Hope it helps!

Comment: Please upvote if the answer was helpful for you! It will help other people to know if the answer is the correcto one